# Axis plotting in python - matplotlib

Tags: python, graph, matplotlib, gridlines

I currently have a plot for my data, with a vertical line in red marking the point where "average number of spins" is. I was wondering if is possible to change the marker for the points for "millionspins,millions" into a blue/black thin cross, and to place major/minor gridlines onto both axis? All the available help online seems to draw from modules that we do not have.
Also how do you label the red line that I have plotted to be "average number of spins"?

Many thanks.

```
matplotlib.pyplot.scatter(millionspins,millions)
plt.xlabel("Number of spins")
plt.plot([averageiterations,averageiterations],[1000000,1500000],'r-')
plt.xlim(0,max(millionspins))
plt.ylim(1000000,max(millions))
plt.ylabel("Bank")
plt.xlim(0,max(millionspins))
plt.ylim(1000000,max(millions))
show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is:

```
ax = plt.gca()
ax.grid(True)
ax.plot(millionspins, millions, marker='+', color='b')
```

Unless you need to make each marker a different size or color, I would suggest using `plot` instead of `scatter` because it is faster and you can more easily modify it later (if you want to do animations).

Comment: Okay thanks for that I have a much nicer plot now. Do you know how I would add a legend to for my "millionspins,millions" section? And another bit in my legend for "average spins"?

Comment: You should ask a new question (or search existing questions as I know that has been answered) about your legend.

Answer (score 1):

Use `marker='+'` to make the [marker a thin cross](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.scatter):

```
plt.scatter(millionspins, millions, c='b', marker='+')
```

Use [plt.grid](http://matplotlib.org/api/axis_api.html#matplotlib.axis.Axis.grid) to show grid lines:

```
plt.grid(True, which='both')
```

---

By the way, you could use `plt.axvline` to create the red vertical line. That way, if the user rescales the plot, the endpoints of the vertical line won't show:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
N = 100
millionspins = np.random.randint(10000000, size=N)
millions = np.random.randint(10000000, size=N)
averageiterations = millionspins.mean()

plt.scatter(millionspins, millions, marker='+')
plt.axvline([averageiterations], color='r')

plt.xlabel("Number of spins")
plt.ylabel("Bank")

plt.xlim(0,max(millionspins))
plt.ylim(1000000,max(millions))

plt.grid(True, which='both')
plt.show()
```

[image]